# Cannot convert expression of type *json.RawMessage to type []byte in golang

Tags: json, go

[code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySCxW.png)

I was experiencing this problem when using golang's elasticsearch client "elastic".

*json.RawMessage is a type of []byte.If I not write []byte() to cast type, it said cannot use 'resp.Source' (type *json.RawMessage) as type []byte.

The environment is go 1.10.3 and elastic 6.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `*json.RawMesasge` is not a `[]byte`.  It's a pointer.

Dereference the pointer to convert to a slice of bytes:

```
 byteSlice := []byte(*pointerToRawMessage)
```